# Installing Debian 10, upgrade to stable later?

Tags: debian

I need a new server that will be storing a lot of data, I know that Debian 10 stable will be released soon. But wanted to know if I install Debian 10 right now and start configuring the server, then once Debian 10 gets a stable release, I will be able to upgrade to the stable version easily using `apt upgrade`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually you won't even have to upgrade or do anything, it will happen on its own: *buster* will become *stable*.

If you're using the code name *buster* rather than the archive name *testing* for the repositories, then there's nothing to do. If the installation used *testing* you can change it to *buster* yourself (in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`).

When the *stable* "pointer" will move from *stretch* (the codename for Debian 9) to *buster* (codename for future Debian 10), *buster* will become *the* stable version of Debian, without any intervention from your side. You'll only notice it because the rate of upgrades will probably slow down.

Note: of course, as OP and wurtel said, usual upgrades have still to be done regularly (for example with `apt update` + `apt upgrade`) for anything to happen.

Comment: +1. It’s better to use release codenames in general in `sources.list`. The Debian 10 installer specifies `buster`.

Comment: sounds good. Is there a netint iso for Debian 10?

Comment: I found the link for the netinst https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/buster_di_rc1/amd64/iso-cd/debian-buster-DI-rc1-amd64-netinst.iso

Comment: Of course you will still have to upgrade, otherwise you may not have all the correct versions that buster relases with. You just don't have to change any sources.list files for apt.

Comment: @wurtel right, I didn't even consider it with this angle. I'll add something about this

Answer (score 2):

You may need to run `apt update` and then verify that you want to move from "testing buster" to "stable buster".  For example:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
```

Using `aptitude` or `apt-get update` may not transition without an error.  You might get an error that looks like:

```
$ apt-get update
E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
```